# Call web service from .net 3.5 windows service

Tags: web-services, .net-3.5, windows-services

I'm building a new windows service with .net 3.5 and unlike 2.0 you cannot just add a web reference to a web service.  Can you call a .net 2.0 web service from a .net 3.5 windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean [that?](http://www.techtoolblog.com/archives/add-web-references-to-visual-studio-2008)